# Path.GetFileName(inputFile) is returning incorrect file name due to having spaces

Tags: c#, .net, file, command-line

Is this a bug for c# 4.5 for the method Path.GetFilenAME(FILE) to return a file name with spaces up until only the first space? I came across this issue, and didn't realise what was going on at first. An example code and outcome is shown below:

```
//ex: args[0] = "C:\Users\cpharr\Desktop\Testruns\New_Test_2014 test file.pdf"

String inputFile = args[0];                                
String tempFileName = Path.GetFileName(inputFile);

//or ....

String inputFile = Path.GetFileName(args[0]);                                

//inputFile is now equal to "New_Test_2014 as the file name instead of New_Test_2014 test file.pdf."
```

Comment: `args[0]` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Probably: args[0] = "C:\Users\cpharr\Desktop\Testruns\New_Test_2014"
args[1] = "test"
args[2] = "file.pdf"

Comment: I am use to them always using an underscore, the file path to the file, and the out path.  The file names always have an underscore, so I didn't even think of the argument cause.  That was an idiot move by me, but thought I should log it incase it was. WOW, I am sad to be developing right nw by missing that one....

Comment: Yea I see now.  arguments would be arg1: file arg2: test arg:3 2013_testing.pdf.   Sorry guys for wasting the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing file names on the command-line that contain spaces, you need to wrap them in double quotes. When you launch your .exe, it should be called like this:

```
myprog.exe "c:\path\with spaces\in the\middle\file.pdf"
```

If you don't, the system command-line parser will treat each segment as a separate command-line parameter. That will cause your program to receive multiple parameters in the `args` array. This is standard behavior in Windows, any program taking command-line parameters would work this way (not just .NET programs).

Comment: . I am such an idiot. I didn't even think about that, but completely know that...  lol   So this works if initialized in code...  Thanks again.

Comment: @Casey Heh, don't feel bad about it, I ran into this more than once myself, even though I know how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Lol.  Yea, you end writing some nice elegant cool and complicated stuff, then it is these little bugs that get you sometimes.

Comment: See, I have a Powershell script that runs this console app and gets these two parameters as arguments, they are not human typed. So ideally, I should add quotes if needed in the powershell script before passing the arguments to my console application and calling it.

Comment: @Casey If you're launching your program by building a command-line string, then yes, you should just always put quotes around the file names (assuming a double quote is not part of your filenames).

Comment: For sure. I have so many [projects going on, sometimes I overlook the obvious. It only supplies a file and path to save the file also. Not much in the param world.